# Crop last N lines of a string to display in userform textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to display a textlog string in a userform's textbox.

Code might look like this:

```
Dim public textlog as string

sub button1_click()
' do some action
textlog = textlog & event_string & vbCrLf
'event_string might exceed more than 2 line 
textlog = textlog & "button1 action" & vbCrLf
userform1.textbox1.text = textlog 
end sub

sub button2_click()
' do some action
textlog = textlog & event_string & vbCrLf
'event_string might exceed more than 2 line 
textlog = textlog & "button2 action" & vbCrLf
userform1.textbox1.text = textlog 
end sub
```

However, the textbox should only contain 20 lines of information, while my
the contents of my textlog will exceed 20 lines.

How can I display only the latest (last) 20 lines of the textlog in textbox1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to return only the last N lines of a string, and then display that in your textbox.

Note that you have to specify what the line break character is. Depending on your specific application, it could be `vbCrLf`, `vbCr`, `vbLf`, or even some other delimiter.

```
Function GetLastLines(ByVal s As String, ByVal nLinesToDisplay As Long, _
    Optional ByVal lineBreakChar As String = vbCrLf)

    'Split the string into an array
    Dim splitString() As String
    splitString = Split(s, lineBreakChar)

    'How many lines are there?
    Dim nLines As Long
    nLines = UBound(splitString) + 1

    If nLines <= nLinesToDisplay Then
        'No need to remove anything. Get out.
        GetLastLines = s
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Collect last N lines in a new array
    Dim lastLines() As String
    ReDim lastLines(0 To nLinesToDisplay - 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(lastLines)
        lastLines(i) = splitString(i + nLines - nLinesToDisplay)
    Next i

    'Join the lines array into a single string
    GetLastLines = Join(lastLines, lineBreakChar)
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
MsgBox GetLastLines( _
    "line 1" & vbCrLf & "line 2" & vbCrLf & "line 3" & vbCrLf _
        & "line 4" & vbCrLf & "line 5" & vbCrLf & "line 6", _
    4, vbCrLf)
```

Only the last 4 lines are displayed:

[image]

Note that this assumes that your last line is *not* terminated by a line break. If it is, then you can tweak the code to deal with that.

Alternatively, you can use Excel's built-in `SUBSTITUTE` function, which is useful in this particular case, because it can locate a specific instance of a given character. So instead of building arrays you can use a one-liner:

```
Function GetLastLines2(ByVal s As String, ByVal nLinesToDisplay As Long, _
    Optional ByVal lineBreakChar As String = vbCrLf)

    'An arbitrary character that will never be in your input string:
    Dim delim As String: delim = Chr(1)

    'How many lines are there?
    Dim nLines As Long
    nLines = UBound(Split(s, lineBreakChar)) + 1

    If nLines <= nLinesToDisplay Then
        'No need to remove anything. Get out.
        GetLastLines2 = s
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Replace one line break with delim, split the string on it, 
    'return only second part:
    GetLastLines2 = Split( _
        WorksheetFunction.Substitute( _
            s, lineBreakChar, delim, nLines - nLinesToDisplay), _
        delim)(1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = "Cat" & vbcrlf & "Tiger" & vbcrlf & "Lion" & vbcrlf & "Shark hunting florida lynxs" & vbcrlf & "Leopard" & vbcrlf & "Cheetah"
A= StrReverse(A)
NumLines = 3
i=1
For X = 1 to NumLines
    i = Instr(i, A, vbcr) + 1
Next

Msgbox StrReverse(Left(A, i - 1))
```

This is a program that cuts or leaves lines from top or bottom of files.

To use

**Cut**

```
filter cut {t|b} {i|x} NumOfLines
```

Cuts the number of lines from the top or bottom of file.

```
t - top of the file
b - bottom of the file
i - include n lines
x - exclude n lines
```

**Example**

```
cscript //nologo filter.vbs cut t i 5 < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

The script

```
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 
        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        LineCount = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            LineCount = LineCount + 1
            .AddNew
            .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop

        .Sort = "LineNumber ASC"

        If LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LCase(Arg(3))
            End If
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3))
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            End If
        End If

        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
```